# JUnit test in Spring - overriding and ignoring beans from application other configuration classes

Tags: spring, configuration, junit, javabeans

We have large application written in Spring 3. I need to write JUnit test checking behavior of some service. It is not a unit but part of a system. There are some services and repositories working together insite it -> lot of injected beans inside. The app also uses aspects.

**My question is. How to manage config and beans in this case of tests?** I need to use beans defined in app configes and in tests only redefine beans using persistence to work with a embedded db. So I need to use beans from src as they are defined and override only some causing troubles (persistance beans, beans using webservices,...)
In test package I made Config class definying beans for persistance, using datasource for hsql. But I don`t know what next. I tried to annotate Test config class with:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
@EnableTransactionManagement(mode = AdviceMode.ASPECTJ, proxyTargetClass = true)
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.example.our.app")
public class MyTestConfig implements TransactionManagementConfigurer {
```

to scan whole application and use configuration of beans from src folder. But this also takes configs from other tests causing problems. Is this whole good strategy or not? What now - use excludeFilters to remove other test configs? Or is this strategy whole bad?

thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can selectively overwrite beans with the context merging functionality supplied by the `@ContextHierarchy` annotation.

In order to get this working for your use case you will have to create a base context that scans your app for Spring beans:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan({"com.example.our.app"})
public class MyTestConfig implements TransactionManagementConfigurer {
```

Then create a base class that utilizes this context and names it **- this won't work with named contexts!**:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextHierarchy( {
    @ContextConfiguration(name="testContext", classes = MyTestConfig.class),
})
public class BaseTest {
```

And finally write a unit test that extends the base class and defines a new context under the same name to overwrite individual beans with a test specific configuration:

```
    @ContextHierarchy(@ContextConfiguration(name="testContext", classes = OneUnitTest.Config.class))
    public class OneUnitTest extends AggroBaseTest {
      @Configuration
      static class Config {      
            ..
      }
```

Answer (score 2):

I think best way here to use is [Spring profiles](http://blog.springsource.org/2011/02/14/spring-3-1-m1-introducing-profile/).
Check [here now to use H2 for tests](http://hillert.blogspot.com/2011/04/spring-31-bean-definition-profiles-for.html) with profiles.

Comment: Yes good point but you will have to move the configuration from applicationContext.xml  to java

Answer (score 0):

You can also override with another import

```
<beans>
    <import resource="classpath*:applocationContext.xml" />
    <bean id="dataSourceFactory" class=com.demo.MyNewClass/>
</beans>
```

And in you class if you

```
this.applicationContext.getBean("dataSourceFactory");
```

retrieve the class, you would see the instance of new class

Further

```
<bean id="dataSourceFactory" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource" >
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}"/>
    <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}"/>
    <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}"/>
    <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}"/>
</bean>
```

So there are different ways you can override the default behaviour