# How to handle xml file path given using regular expression to support multiple environment for Integration Testing by Spring?

Tags: java, spring, integration-testing, junit4

I have following configuration in my test-appContext.xml file for supporting execution of spring integration testing.

```xml
<bean id="cacheManagerConfig" class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheManagerFactoryBean"> 
    <property name="configLocation" value="file:/web/${websphere.env}/${websphere.Domain}/${websphere.Name}/myportal/config/ehcache.xml"/>
</bean>
```

I am using junit 4.12 with spring 4 for Integration Testing of MVC flow.
***How to handle ehcache.xml file path in spring integration testing.***

Thanks :)

Comment: Take a look on this, maybe this is what you need: https://stackoverflow.com/q/15573822/11733759

Comment: Thanks @Iczapski but this is not useful in my case, expression under the value attribute of property tag takes values from jvm.options file( for Liberty Server) from corresponding environment like DEV, UAT, STAGE etc but in test environment there is no such jvm.options file. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the solution, as expression retrieving value from System Property which jvm.options file in case of Liberty server so i used following code in test case class.

```
static {
        System.setProperty("websphere.env", "test");
        System.setProperty("websphere.Domain", "mytestdomain");
        System.setProperty("websphere.Name", "mytestdomain");

    }
```

Its working fine.